# Dynamic SCSS Overflow trimming

Tags: html, css, sass

I found an intriguing SCSS example of [dynamic moving background colors, Floating Stained Glass Effect](https://blog.prototypr.io/5-css-animated-backgrounds-to-inspire-your-next-project-97fdb692e852).  Think multi-colored lava lamp.  Here's the original [codepen.](https://codepen.io/hylobates-lar/pen/GRowVvx)

[image: Pretty colors]

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple "clip" of that background content and display a div with the dynamic color content... My current [codepen](https://codepen.io/zipzit/pen/KKXGmYN) and the display.

[image: pretty colors in box]

What I'm looking for is the dynamic content only in the inscribed "box" with everything else on the screen pure white.

```
   <div class="splash box">
      <div class="splash_head" />
      <div class="splash_body" />
   </div>
```

All my attempts at `overflow: hidden;` have failed miserably.  Not sure how to beat the `position: fixed;` code within

```
.splash_head::before,
.splash_head::after,
.splash_body::before,
.splash_body::after {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  content: "V";
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  animation: 44s -27s move infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I wrap the content with an additional surround container, I'm able to get what I asked for.

```
<div class="surround">
  <div class="splash box">
    <div class="splash_head" />
    <div class="splash_body" />
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.surround {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And it looks pretty.

[image: Pretty with white border]

Unfortunately, this example as written was a minimum problem statement. And in a static HTML web page, these div containers would work great.  Unfortunately my actual use case is a complex SvelteKit application, with nested slots where the color bleed thru is terrible.  It's not clear if this is a z-index issue or something else.  But yeah, it's ugly, sigh.

The other issue here is with the pretty lava lamp stuff is a significant Lighthouse website ranking performance degradation. (71 goes down to 63)  At this point, not sure it's worth spending time on. I may just create a static site, grab some screen shots of the pretty pictures and use them static. I'm really just looking for a subtle but interesting splash of color.